# Repeated String Match: need help to understand the maximum number of repeats needed to be looked at

Tags: algorithms, search-problem, substrings, string-matching

There's this question on LeetCode [(link)](https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-string-match/):

> Given two strings `A` and `B`, find the minimum number of times `A` has to be repeated such that `B` is a substring of it. If no such solution exists, return `-1`.
>
> For example, with `A = "abcd"` and `B = "cdabcdab"`.
>
> Return `3`, because by repeating `A` three times (`“abcdabcdabcd”`), `B` is a substring of it; and `B` is not a substring of `A` repeated two times (`"abcdabcd"`).
>
> Note:
>   The length of `A` and `B` will be between `1` and `10000`.

The brute force solution provided on the website is this:

> The question can be summarized as "What is the smallest `k` for which `B`
>   is a substring of `A * k`?" We can simply try every `k`.
>
> #### Algorithm
>
> Imagine we wrote `S = A+A+A+...`. If `B` is to be a substring of `S`, we
>   only need to check whether some `S[0:], S[1:], ..., S[len(A) - 1:]`
>   starts with `B`, as `S` is long enough to contain `B`, and `S` has period at 
>   most `len(A)`.
>
> Now, suppose `q` is the least number for which `len(B) <= len(A * q)`. We
>   only need to check whether B is a substring of `A * q` or `A * (q+1)`. If
>   we try `k < q`, then `B` has larger length than `A * q` and therefore can't
>   be a substring. When `k = q+1`, `A * k` is already big enough to try all
>   positions for `B`; namely, `A[i:i+len(B)] == B` for `i = 0, 1, ..., len(A) - 1`.

I understand this part:

> If we try `k < q`, then `B` has larger length than `A * q` and therefore can't
>   be a substring.

But I don't follow how the writer has arrived at this other conclusion:

> When `k = q+1`, `A * k` is already big enough to try all
>   positions for `B`; namely, `A[i:i+len(B)] == B` for `i = 0, 1, ..., len(A) - 1`.

Why can we stop at `k = q+1`? Why is it not necessary to try `q+2` (and `q+3`, etc.)?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a link to the source of the copied material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof by example. We want to check whether $B$ is a substring of some power of $A$. Instead, let us check whether $B$ is a substring of $A^\omega$, that is, $A$ repeated infinitely many times. It suffices to test the following starting positions (why?):

```
abcdabcdabcdabcd...
cdabcdab

abcdabcdabcdabcd...
 cdabcdab

abcdabcdabcdabcd...
  cdabcdab

abcdabcdabcdabcd...
   cdabcdab
```

In order to perform these checks, we don't need to consider $A^\omega$; it suffices to consider the smallest power of $A$ which covers the very last case. This power is $q+1$ (or possibly just $q$).

Comment: Is "proof by example" an acceptable way to prove correctness of algorithms? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_example): _Proof by example (also known as inappropriate generalization) is a logical fallacy whereby one or more examples are claimed as "proof" for a more general statement._. Can you by any chance provide a general proof?

Comment: Before you can prove something, you need to understand why it’s true. I hope I helped with that. Now *you* can provide a general proof.